# how to replace substring of column values with dictionary keys in pandas

Tags: pandas, dictionary, replace

I know I can replace column values with dictionary keys in pandas with

`dictionary={'A': 'Y'}`

`df[col].replace(dictionary, inplace=True)`

but what if I have a column value "A;B" and I want to replace only A with Y

Comment: do you need ```df['column_name'].str.replace('A','Y')``` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for a,b in dictionary.items():
     df[col] = df[col].Title.str.replace(a,b)
```